# What is the best way to represent any XML schema into data structure?

Tags: perl, data-structures, xsd, xml-parsing

I am trying to represent any XML schema into data structure, which maintain the hierarchy of that schema and positions of each element in the schema. Any suggestions?

Comment: I used Perl in case you want to know the language.

Comment: I'm just curious, please clarify: Are you asking about deserializing xml documents, or about representing an _XSL_ schema definition in Perl?

Comment: I am doing schema matching between two schema elements. The matching process is based on name matching(e.g. WordNet) and structure matching and this why I would like to maintain the hierarchy of XML schema elements to know parent, child, and sibling of specific element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML Schemas are themselves XML so most comprehensive XML libraries will work for you, depending on what you want to do when you have the structure built. I recommend [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML) or [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig).

Comment: I am not sure if it will suit the schema matching between two schema elements. Especially, if I do structure matching (parent, siblings and children of each XML elements). BTW I did not know that XML-SCHEMA are treated like XML so thanks for this info.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you've trying to do would be best accomplished with [XML::Validator::Schema](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-Validator-Schema) module. Technically, the correct answer is XML::Validator::Schema::Parser (which, as you guess it, parses schema into data structure), but it's an internal module. But maybe its analysis will be helpful as well.

Comment: Unfortunately,it is for schema matching. This why I will have to maintain the hierarchy.

Comment: So... doesn't that mean you may use XML::Validator::Schema to validate the document right-out, without parsing the schema by your code? )